# obtener la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con javascript y php

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas, estoy trabajando en un formulario en php donde tengo los datos de una persona y quiero que al poner la fecha de nacimiento en formato dd/mm/aaaa me calcule automáticamente la edad y lo ponga en el campo edad. esto se puede hacer con javascript?

Answer (score 10):

Sí, se puede hacer con JavaScript.

De [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/6252597) de Stack Overflow en ingles:

```
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
    var hoy = new Date();
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }

    return edad;
}
```

Para ponerlo en el campo deseado:

```
document.querySelector("#miCampo").textContent = calcularEdad(fecha);
```

Answer (score 3):

Otra opción:

```
function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birthday_arr = birthday.split("/");
    var birthday_date = new Date(birthday_arr[2], birthday_arr[1] - 1, birthday_arr[0]);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday_date.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

var age = calculateAge("15/04/1976");
alert( age );
```

Comment: Esta si me funciono. No la otra que tiene 4 puntos. si se coloca 26-07-1990 tira NaN

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer con PHP de manera mucho mas fácil intenta esto solo asegúrate de que la fecha de nacimiento sea una fecha valida con el formato "año-mes-dia" y fecha se divide por la cantidad de segundos de un año natural

```
$fecha = time() - strtotime($nacimiento);

$edad = floor($fecha / 31556926);
```

esto te tendría que dar la cantidad de años cumplidos de una persona!

Saludos

Comment: No me funciono. Una de las fechas en las cuales la edad no funciona es 26-07-1990. Aparece NaN

Comment: Hola @santiago, quizás no te funciono por que Jonathan dice que el formato tiene que ser "año-mes-dia" y el formato de la fecha que indicas es "dia-mes-año", revisa eso, lo que podrías hacer es formatear tus fechas para que las obligues a que tengan el formato de yyyy-mm-dd, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

[obtener la edad (años, meses y días) a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con javascript](http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2017/01/obtener-la-edad-anos-meses-y-dias.html)

Función calcularEdad (años, meses y días)

```
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
        // Si la fecha es correcta, calculamos la edad

        if (typeof fecha != "string" && fecha && esNumero(fecha.getTime())) {
            fecha = formatDate(fecha, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        var values = fecha.split("-");
        var dia = values[2];
        var mes = values[1];
        var ano = values[0];

        // cogemos los valores actuales
        var fecha_hoy = new Date();
        var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
        var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth() + 1;
        var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();

        // realizamos el calculo
        var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;
        if (ahora_mes < mes) {
            edad--;
        }
        if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia)) {
            edad--;
        }
        if (edad > 1900) {
            edad -= 1900;
        }

        // calculamos los meses
        var meses = 0;

        if (ahora_mes > mes && dia > ahora_dia)
            meses = ahora_mes - mes - 1;
        else if (ahora_mes > mes)
            meses = ahora_mes - mes
        if (ahora_mes < mes && dia < ahora_dia)
            meses = 12 - (mes - ahora_mes);
        else if (ahora_mes < mes)
            meses = 12 - (mes - ahora_mes + 1);
        if (ahora_mes == mes && dia > ahora_dia)
            meses = 11;

        // calculamos los dias
        var dias = 0;
        if (ahora_dia > dia)
            dias = ahora_dia - dia;
        if (ahora_dia < dia) {
            ultimoDiaMes = new Date(ahora_ano, ahora_mes - 1, 0);
            dias = ultimoDiaMes.getDate() - (dia - ahora_dia);
        }

        return edad + " años, " + meses + " meses y " + dias + " días";
    }
```

Función esNumero

```
function esNumero(strNumber) {
    if (strNumber == null) return false;
    if (strNumber == undefined) return false;
    if (typeof strNumber === "number" && !isNaN(strNumber)) return true;
    if (strNumber == "") return false;
    if (strNumber === "") return false;
    var psInt, psFloat;
    psInt = parseInt(strNumber);
    psFloat = parseFloat(strNumber);
    return !isNaN(strNumber) && !isNaN(psFloat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta función:

```
function calculate_age(birth_month, birth_day, birth_year) {
  today_date = new Date();
  today_year = today_date.getFullYear();
  today_month = today_date.getMonth();
  today_day = today_date.getDate();
  age = today_year - birth_year;

  if (today_month < (birth_month - 1)) {
    age--;
  }
  if (((birth_month - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_day)) {
    age--;
  }
  console.log(age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si has recogido las fechas por separado, la forma mas limpia y sencilla sería la siguiente:

```
function calcularAños(dia, mes, año) {
    var today = new Date();
    //Restamos los años
    años = today.getFullYear() - año;
    // Si no ha llegado su cumpleaños le restamos el año por cumplir (Los meses en Date empiezan en 0, por eso tenemos que sumar 1)
    if (mes > (today.getMonth() + 1) || dia > today.getDay())
        años--;
    return años;
}
```

En caso de no haberlo hecho así solamente tendrías que estraer los datos:

```
function calcularAños(fechaNacimiento) {
    var today = new Date();
    //Restamos los años
    años = today.getFullYear() - año;
    // Si no ha llegado su cumpleaños le restamos el año por cumplir
    if (fechaNacimiento.getMonth() > (today.getMonth()) || fechaNacimiento.getDay() > today.getDay())
        años--;
    return años;
}
```

Es similar a la respuesta de Cameron637. Aunque a lo mejor mas comprendible.
Un saludo