# Calcular edad en php

Tags: php, mysql

Cómo se puede obtener edad a partir de fecha de nacimiento en formato Date yyyy-mm-dd

```
while ($fila=$resul1->fetch_assoc()) {

   $tiempo = strtotime($fila['fecha_nac']); 
   $ahora = time(); 
   $edad = ($ahora-$tiempo)/(60*60*24*365.25); 
   $edadFinal = floor($edad); 

  $pdf->Cell(45,6, 'Edad:'.utf8_decode($edadFinal).'') ,0,'J');

}
```

Me imprime -1 en edadFinal

Comment: Hola @IndiraRivas, puede que esto te ayude https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31373/obtener-la-edad-a-partir-de-la-fecha-de-nacimiento-con-javascript-y-php, en la segunda respuesta sale como se puede hacer en PHP.

Comment: Me sigue imprimiendo -1