# Validar formulario con base a una edad limite de un input date

Tags: php, javascript, html

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo validar en un formulario dependiendo de una fecha ingresada si la edad del usuario es mayor a 15 anios, tomando en cuenta la fecha actual, gracias.
Intente poner el atributo MAX pero no puedo establecer fechas fijas

`<input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" require>`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo por medio de `Javascript` de la siguiente manera:

Pero primero tienes que asignarle un `id` a tu `input`:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="test" required>
```

Para posteriormente hacer uso del `valor` de ese `input`:

```
var fecha = document.getElementById("test").value;
var edad = calcularEdad(fecha);

if(edad > 15){
    // aqui haces lo que quieras con la validacion de si es mayor a 15
    alert("El usuario es mayor a 15 años").
}
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
    var hoy = new Date();
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }

    return edad;
}
```

Referencia: [Obtener la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31380/4229)

Answer (score 1):

Se debe validar en el Frontend y en el Backend, ya que si la validación solo la haces desde el cliente, el mismo puede cambiar la fecha de su computador y por lo tanto podría adulterar la información, por eso debemos validar igualmente en el Backend.

Prueba lo siguiente:

- En el Front con JS lo puedes hacer pasando la variable fecha desde el servidor con PHP.

```
   var fecha_nacimiento = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha_nacimiento").value);
   var fecha_actual = "<?php echo new DateTime(); ?>";

function calcularEdad(fecha_nacimiento) {
    var diferenciaEdad = fecha_actual - fecha_nacimiento.getTime();
    var edad = new Date(diferenciaEdad);
    return Math.abs(edad.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

- En el Backend lo puedes hacer al enviar el POST, validas la fecha recibida con la fecha del servidor nuevamente.

```php
   $fecha_nacimiento = new DateTime("1991-09-30");
   $fecha_actual =     new DateTime();
   $edad = $fechaActual->diff($fecha_nacimiento);
```