# Calcular edad en javascript en campo de Acrobat a partir de fecha de nacimiento

Tags: javascript, formularios

Buenas agradeceré ayuda en el siguiente problema.
Requiero calcular edad a partir de fecha de nacimiento en formulario PDF (Acrobat Pro)
El resultado debería ser algo A años, B meses y C días
Idealmente el script debería omitir años, meses o días si su valor es 0
He encontrado algunas respuestas en el post:
[obtener la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con javascript y php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31373/obtener-la-edad-a-partir-de-la-fecha-de-nacimiento-con-javascript-y-php/31380). Pero no tengo los conocimientos para adaptarlo a Acrobat.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.